# want to selectively print using awk

Tags: awk

My input is like below code :

```
/vol/vol1/  -sec=sys,rw=hostname1-nfs:@netgrp_admin1:@netgrp_admin2:hostname2-nfs,root=hostname1-nfs:@netgrp_admin1:@netgrp_admin2:hostname2-nfs
```

I want to selectively print the output as :

```
hostname1-nfs:@netgrp_admin1:@netgrp_admin2:hostname2-nfs
```

possibly using `awk` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way using a regex as Field Separator in awk:

`awk '{print $4":"$5":"$6":"$7}' FS='=|:|,' input_file`

Comment: When you have multiple single separators, you do not need `regex`: `awk -F"[=:,]" '{print $4,$5,$6,$7}' OFS=\:`